# A Moat Sits on a Hill, in A Desert, Around Black Abyss

Tags: riddle

> A moat sits on a hill, in a desert, around a black abyss. 
>   By light the tide comes in, and by night the tide goes out.
>
> The moat is never emptied, the abyss is never filled, and the desert
>   is never green.
>   The waters are often muddy, but rarely blue, and sometimes green.
>
> There is no passage from the desert to the abyss --the moat a perfect,
>   unbroken circle, with no bridge and no crossing. Only one thing may enter, never to escape.

Who or what may enter, and where is this abyss?

Comment: Thanks for this - one of the few riddles on this site that I could solve without looking at the answers!

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it wasn't too challenging or abstract. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is referring to

> An eye; specifically, the [iris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_(anatomy)).

*A moat sits on a hill, in a desert, around a black abyss.*

> The hill is the dome of the eyeball.  The desert is the white of the eye.  The black abyss is the pupil.

*By light the tide comes in, and by night the tide goes out.*

> With more light, the pupil shrinks and the iris appears bigger.  With less light, the pupil expands and the iris appears smaller.

*The moat is never emptied, the abyss is never filled, and the desert is never green.*

> Though the pupil expands and contracts, neither the pupil nor the iris never disappears completely.  The white of the eye remains white (not green).

*The waters are often muddy, but rarely blue, and sometimes green.*

> Most often, eyes (irises) are brown, but sometimes blue or green.

*There is no passage from the desert to the abyss --the moat a perfect, unbroken circle, with no bridge and no crossing.*

> The iris completely surrounds the pupil.  You have to cross it to get from the pupil to the white of the eye.

*Only one thing may enter, never to escape.*

> Light is the only thing that can enter, and once it is absorbed by the eye, it doesn't leave.

Comment: That must be it! Great job. I stared at it for minutes; I was stumped.

Comment: You are 1 minute earlier than me,+1

Comment: Excellent! Great description! You got it! +1